# Is it possible to filter/block sellers without free return while searching on Amazon?

Tags: amazon

I usually don't want to buy stuff on amazon if I can't return it for free. For some sellers, you have to pay the shipping cost when you return the stuff.

While searching for products, can I filter sellers without free return out of the search results?